# Javascript Creating Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, createelement

I Am on that script for 2 days and I think I lost in somewhere... First Click is ok , second click is ok but after second click the main idea is lost...

What I want is after click "EKLE" Button add new  with The input Value..

But after second click "first element add new  tags..

I want only "Yeni İstasyon Ekleyin" button adds new elements..

I hope I told what I meant... :/

```js
$("#istasyonismispan").click(function() {
  document.getElementById("istasyonismispan").innerHTML = "";
  id = document.getElementById("istasyonismispan").id;
  divareastn = document.getElementById(id);
  divareastn.style.height = "100px";
  divareastn.style.paddingTop = "10px";
  divareastn.style.backgroundColor = "#D8C7B4";
  input = '<input   type="text" id="inputid' + id + '"    style="width:260px;height: 35px;padding-left: 1rem" class="form-control form-control-sm"  placeholder="İstasyon İsmi Giriniz...">';
  newbutton = '<button  type="text" id="buttonid' + id + '"   style="width:260px;height: 35px;margin-top: -2rem"  class="addstation btn btn-sm btn-primary bi bi-plus-square" onclick="eklebutton(this.id)">   EKLE...</button>';
  divareastn.innerHTML = input + "<br>" + newbutton;
  document.getElementById("inputid" + id).focus();
});


function eklebutton(id) {
  mainid = id.substr(8);
  id = id.replace(/\s/g, '');
  inputid = "inputid" + mainid;
  mainid = document.getElementById(inputid).value;
  buttonid = "buttonid" + mainid;
  stationid = document.getElementById(inputid).value;
  stationidcheck = stationid.replace(/\s/g, '');
  istasyonismispan = "istasyonismispan" + stationidcheck;


  if (stationidcheck != "") {
    document.getElementById("istasyonismispan").innerHTML = "";
    headerofstation = '<h4><span class="float-md-start text-dark" > ' + stationid + '</span></h4>';
    newinnerhtml = headerofstation + '<p id="" style="width:260px;height: 35px;margin-top: 1rem" class="float-md-start bi bi-plus-square" > YENİ GÖREV EKLE...</p>'
    document.getElementById("istasyonismispan").innerHTML = newinnerhtml;
    document.getElementById("istasyonismispan").id = istasyonismispan;

    divarea = document.getElementById("kanbanrow");
    newtag = document.createElement("A");
    newtag.style.width = "310px";
    newtag.innerHTML =
      '<a style="width:300px;height: 40px;line-height: 40px;padding-left: 20px;" id="istasyonismispan"  class="float-md-start hoverback " ><span class="bi bi-plus-square"></span>    Yeni İstasyon Ekleyin</a>';
    divarea.appendChild(newtag);
  } else {
    alert("LÜTFEN İSTASYON BAŞLIĞI GİRİNİZ");
  }

};
```

```css
div.scrollmenu {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hoverback {
  background: rgba(113, 199, 230, 1);
}

.hoverback:hover {
  background: rgba(113, 199, 230, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div class="scrollmenu ">
    <div class=" float-md-start " id="kanbanrow">
      <a style="width:300px;height: 40px;line-height: 40px;padding-left: 20px;" id="istasyonismispan" class="hoverback text-white  "><span class="bi bi-plus-square"></span>    Yeni İstasyon Ekleyin</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this ?

Comment: I solved more than that, what you wanna learn?